Routing Potable Water Supply Lines
I'd like to move some of the fixtures in our bathroom. The bathroom is an addition and access to the space underneath is very limited and difficult.
So, I'm thinking about running the supply lines overhead in PEX. In one corner of the bathroom I have reasonable access from the crawl space, I could come up there and then run above the ceiling to the wall where I want to put a sink, then I could come down in that wall.
My concern is the possibility of air getting trapped in the run above the ceiling. Is this something I should be worried about?

Open the faucet and any air trapped will come out.  This only happens if the pipe is open/disconnected.  More important is if the pipe/s go though cold/unheated sections and freeze.

So, is bleeding of hot water heat and cooling systems only necessary because they are closed systems? I was thinking that the water might not be able to push air "downhill" and thus the air could stay trapped.

Air will come out of water in a closed system over time, but open systems(sinks/baths) do not have enough time to be a problem, and an open faucet fixes it.

Heating systems use low-power circulating pumps that don't like air bubbles. Plumbing systems use 20-80PSI supply pressures .vs. 0 PSI open faucets. The bubbles will leave in a hurry.
